# SQL count without group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has user_id and purchase_id. I want to filter the table so that only users with more than 2 purchases (i.e. there are more than 2 rows for that user in the table). I used count and group by, but it does not work in a way I want.

```
create view myview as 
select user_Id, purchase_id, count(*) as count from mytable group by user_Id;

select user_id, purchase_id from myview where count >2;
```

But it gives me only users (only one user_id) that has more than 2 purchase and it does not give me all of their purchases. For example if the table looks like this:

```
user_id  purchase_id
1         1212
1         1312
2         1232
1         1321
3         1545
3         4234
```

My query gives me this :

```
1     1212
3     1545
```

But I want this:

```
1         1212
1         1312
1         1321
3         1545
3         4234
```

Comment: `user_Id, purchase_id, count(*)` if you use `GROUP BY`, it is not suggested to add any other column other than the column you index and the functions

Comment: I really do not understand why people downvote my questions. This is my level of intelligence. I cannot be more smart than this so these are the level of my questions. Sorry if you are way smarter than me. If it is not a high level of question for you, just ignore it, why do you downvote it?!

Comment: No I did not downvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your last sql like this

```
select mt.user_id, mt.purchase_id 
from myview mv 
inner join mytable mt 
on mt.user_id=mv.user_id where mv.count >5;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     mytable mt, 
     (SELECT user_id, count(*) AS purchase_count FROM mytable GROUP BY user_id) ct
WHERE
     mt.user_id = ct.user_id AND ct.purchase_count > 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE USER_ID IN (SELECT USER_ID
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY USER_ID
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2)
```

I tested in my netezza,it works. hopefully, it's also working in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try GROUP BY with HAVING comment.

```
SELECT user_Id, purchase_id 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user_Id 
HAVING count( * ) >5
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you want to list the user id's and purchase id's of all users that have over 5 purchases.

In order to do this you could do a join on two queries.
For example:

```
SELECT tblLeft.user_id, 
       tblLeft.purchase_id 
FROM   myview tblLeft 
       JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                    Count(*) AS purchases 
             FROM   myview 
             GROUP  BY user_id 
             HAVING purchases > 1) tblRight 
         ON tblLeft.user_id = tblRight.user_id
```

The tblRight is essentially a table containing the user_id's of all users with over 5 purchases.
We then do a select (tblLeft) and join it on the tbl right, ensuring only customers with over 5 purchases remain.